# Can anybody help me identify the error in this statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

The table looks like this

```
mysql> DESCRIBE tenants;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| domain     | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| database   | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO tenants(name,domain,database) VALUES ('varun','varun.localhost','sms_varun');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'database) VALUES
('varun','varun.localhost','sms_varun')' at line 1
```

I am using mysql  Ver 8.0.30 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: Maybe try a space after "INSERT INTO tenants"?

Comment: Also, maybe try using backticks, some of your column names might be reserved keywords https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D

Answer (score 3):

`DATABASE` is a reserved MySQL keyword ([see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D)), so you will have to escape it in your insert statement (and forever) to make it work:

```sql
INSERT INTO tenants (name, domain, `database`)
VALUES ('varun', 'varun.localhost', 'sms_varun');
```

You should avoid using reserved MySQL keywords for your column and table names.